# UITabBarController's viewControllers, the second one is loaded before the first one

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I'm working with an App and its rootViewController is `UITabBarController`. I assigned `UITabBarController's` `viewController` with NewsViewController(index = 0), MusicViewController(index = 1) and WeatherViewController(index = 2).

This app seems working correctly. However, when the App was launched, I noticed that MusicViewController's viewDidLoad method was invoked before NewsViewController's viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear methods. From my point of view, only NewsViewController's lifecycle methods should be called.

I just cannot understand why viewDidLoad method of MusicViewController(index = 1) is called when the app was launched.

Thanks for any info.

Comment: how you're assigning the views to the tabbar i mean by programmatically or by storyboard?

Comment: @dreamBegin I use storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

when you are using `UITabBarViewController` keep in mind that:

first thing will be load is the `UITabBarViewController`, then it will load the first 3 view controllers from where you are standing.

for example if you are in index 0 it will load view controllers in index 0,1,2.

then when you go to index 1 it will load view controllers in 1,2,3 and so on.

How `UITabBarViewController is working with you right now is the normal behavior for it.

Hope this answer is your question.

Comment: I created another tabbed application with 3 tabItems. For this app, only the first view controller in index 0 is loaded. So I think it might not always the case.

Comment: Fixed? I have this same problem

Answer (score 0):

maybe it's because you've set the music view as the initial view controller try this:-

selected the news view controller:-

[image]

make news view the initial view controller:-

[image]

Comment: Thanks for you info. but UITabBarController should be the 'initial View Controller' as it is to set app's root view controller. NewsViewController is the first view I wanna show and the app looks like expected except the problems I mentioned above.

Comment: as you set the news view as the initial view controller tabbar will be automatically assigned as the root view controller try it.

Comment: I tried but failed, if I set NewsViewController as 'Initial View Controller', UITabBarController won't be loaded to be shown. Do I understand you correctly?

Comment: than something else is wrong its working fine for me in Xcode 7.2